# Resolution versus Time of processing

Tags: opencv, time, resolution

I'm processing an image from my webcam with opencv. How can I know how much time my processor needs for read every pixel of the matrix and show this? The used algorithm don't matter, I need a generic relation between resolution of the image versus time of processing.
Sorry about the english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general way to calculate timings (in vc9):

```
#include <time.h>

main(){
 clock_t t = clock();
 //Some Code
 //..
 t = clock() - t; 
 printf ("\tRuntime: %f seconds.\n",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```